# python requests chunked response

Tags: xml, python-requests, chunked-encoding

I am using the Python Requests package to write a simple rest client.
Here is my code -

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, passwd), stream=True, verify=False)
print('headers: ')
pprint.pprint(r.headers)
print('status: ' + str(r.status_code))
print('text: ' + r.text)
```

Here is the output -

```
headers: 
    {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
     'date': 'Thu, 16 May 2013 03:26:06 GMT',
     'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
     'set-cookie': 'JSESSIONID=779FC39...5698; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'}
status: 200

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\client.py", line 617, in _readinto_chunked
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "C:\...\client.py", line 562, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

The response to that request is XML. Looks like it is chunked.
Is there a special way to read chunked response? I would like to put the entire XML response in one string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only ever use `stream=True` when you're planning on iterating over the content of the response. If you are planning to print the response content immediately then `stream=True` will not give you any performance benefits. It will only ever defer loading the content into memory until you call `r.text` or `r.content` and then it will be loaded into memory. If you want to prevent loading the entire content into memory, check below. For the other issue, try this:

```
print('text:')
print(r.text)
```

or

```
print('text: ' + r.content)
```

If you're on 2.x, `r.text` is a unicode object which may not be able to be transformed to ASCII.

I'm not quite sure why chunked responses wouldn't work without `stream=True`, but the only way to use it properly (without downloading all of it at once like you do with `r.content` or `r.text`) is to use either `iter_content` or `iter_lines`. To collect all of the response content into one string, you can do the following:

```
contents = ''.join(r.iter_content(224))  # stole the number from your comment
```

On a related note: using the `decode` method on the returned string will provide highly inconsistent results. If your API allows it send the `Accept-Encoding` header so you can always be sure to get back data you can decode.

You're not already doing that, so I didn't suggest it, but if you're insistent on print the information, then you're going to need it, especially if it is an API to a internationally popular website.

Comment: sorry, but your statement about stream is not true.
Requests documentation - 
"By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is downloaded immediately. You can override this behavior and defer downloading the response body until you access the Response.content attribute with the stream parameter"

Comment: Continued - not using 'stream=true' for chunked responses results in really weird errors like the one i have shown above. i just tried it, and i got this error - 
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 2: invalid start byte"

i tried the other options you mentioned, and i get the same error.

howvever, this works - 

rString = r.raw.read(224).decode()

here, 224 represent the response byte length.

Comment: @QuestMonger I know `stream=True` is not causing the `UnicodeDecodeError`. That's an encoding issue between the server and you (i.e., trying to print the data). Regardless, I updated my answer with a way to collect all of the response into one string.

Comment: the UnicodeDecodeError problem was with the restful api. it had some encoding/response issues. i am going to accept above answer as its the closest to a solution we got.